# RegEx for finite repetition of alphanumerics

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a RegEx to check the finite repetition of alphabets as well as for numbers in two separate RegEx, but I am trying to combine to one RegEx but it is always returning true.

```
// Alphabetes testing:
/([a-z])\1{4,}/.test("sd0") => false
/([a-z])\1{4,}/.test("adsssssd0") => true
// Numeric testing:
/([0-9])\1{3,}/.test("sd00000ds") => true
/([0-9])\1{3,}/.test("sd00s00ds") => false
/(([a-z])\1{4,})|(([0-9])\1{3,})/.test("sd0sds0sds") => true // always true
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply `/([a-z]{3,})|([0-9]{3,})/`? Not sure why you need back references.

Comment: Perhaps it is because of my english, but I don't understand what you're trying to do `:(`

Comment: I do want return true only if a same char is repetitive more than 3 times.

Comment: hmm.. what about `([a-z0-9])\1{3,}`?

Comment: This is fine. but I want variable length of repetition. Alphas can be > 3. and numbers can be > 5

Comment: To whom it may concern: I restored the [tag:javascript] tag because it explains why the last regex in the question always succeeds when logically it shouldn't. .

Comment: Thanks @Alan Moore. I should use the correct back reference numbering. That's the mistake I have done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
([a-z0-9])\1{3,}
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33rmj)

The problem of your expression is the numbering of the capturing groups. They are numbered in the order of the opening brackets

```
(([a-z])\1{3,})|(([0-9])\1{3,})
12              34
```

So, with your back reference you are always refereing to `(([a-z])\1{3,})`. I am not sure what should happen, if you refer to a group inside the group itself (recursive). It looks like it matches every single character ([Regexr](http://regexr.com?33rmp))

**Update:**

If there are different length requirements, then you need to use an alternation, but you need to refer to different groups in your alternatives!

```
(?:([a-z])\1{4,}|([0-9])\2{3,})
```

`(?:` is a non capturing group ==> it does not count in the backreferences

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33rnh)

Comment: So, I should use two RegEx and no other option for my scenario.

Comment: We could not see in your question, that there are different length requirements for letters and digits!

Comment: Yes, JavaScript's handling of backreferences is truly bizarre.  It's thoroughly discussed in [this blog post](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/fixing-javascript-regexp).

Comment: @AlanMoore, interesting block post, thats is really a surprising behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following regex?

```
([a-z0-9])\1{3,}
```

If what you need is match whenever 3 or more digits/letters are consecutively repeated, that will work.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for EITHER alphabetic OR numeric character sets. `sd0sds0sds` returns `true` because of the `sds` in the middle and at the end.

If you want the string to match BOTH conditions - there should be a three-character letter set and a three-character number set, I don't think this can be done using a single regular expression.

If you want the string to allow a three-character set of either letters or numbers, then the other answers are appropriate (without the backreference):

```
[a-z0-9]{3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last regex has a mistake:

```
(([a-z])\1{4,})|(([0-9])\1{3,})
```

Twice you use the \1 reference, but \1 refers to the first block in parenthesis which actually is

```
([a-z])\1{4,})|(([0-9])\1{3,}
```

Your regex actually works when you correct the reference numbering

```
(([a-z])\2{4,})|(([0-9])\4{3,})
```

See it in action: http://regexr.com?33rnk